# jQuery fadeIn and fadeOut functions do not work on element clicking

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a pop up like thing, where a `div` shows up when I click a link. After some time, it fades away. I am able to show the `div` elements on click with some animation from `animation.css`. But I am unable to make it fade away. Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Clapper</title>


 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="animate.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">

function demoDisplay()
{
document.getElementById("clapper").style.display="block";
document.getElementById("clapperBG").style.display="block";
$("#clapper").fadeOut(200);

}



</script>

<!-- STYLES -->

<style>

 #clapper {
     min-width:200px;
     min-height:200px;
     top:40%;
     background-color:#888;
     left:40%;
     position:absolute;
     z-index:1002;
     display:none;

}

 #clapperBG {
     min-width:100%;
     min-height:100%;
     background-color:#555;
     opacity:0.6;
     position:absolute;
     display:none;
 }


 </style>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="wrapper">


     <div id="main">
     <a href="#" onclick="demoDisplay()" > TEST</a>
     <div id="clapper"  > Some Animation GIF</div>
     <div id="clapperBG" class="animated  flipInY" >Background</div>



     </div>

   </div>

  <footer>
  </footer>




</body>

</html>
```

Please, tell me what's wrong... I tried many examples like `$("#clapper").fadeOut(2000);` and even in `document.ready` but still no good.

Comment: have you tried without this line: `document.getElementById("clapper").style.display="block";`?

Comment: @97ldave Calling `.fadeOut()` isn't going to do anything if the element isn't visible.

Comment: good point, see my answer below.

Comment: Make sure your jQuery is loading. Check your console or try changing the the first two lines to: `$('#clapper, #clapperBG').show();` If nothing shows then your jQuery isn't being loaded. I copy/pasted your code into a local file and jQuery didn't load for me.

Comment: Also I would append the div into your html if you plan on using it as a modal.. If you do that it will keep your HTML clean and unobstructed.

Comment: @97ldave
Thanks a lot :) I think JQuery wasn't loading properly. So Now I am using http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js ... and its working!

Answer (score 3):

Try using [fadeToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/) on the element you want to fade in/out and using jQuery [.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event on the `<a>` tag:

```
$("a").click(function() {
    $("#clapper").fadeToggle();
});
```

Changing HTML to this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
     <div id="main">
     <a href="#"> TEST</a>
     <div id="clapper"> Some Animation GIF</div>
     <div id="clapperBG" class="animated flipInY">Background</div>
</div>
```

Exmaple here: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/uG76H/)

Answer (score 2):

Chaining the [$.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/), [$.delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/), and $.hide() functions seems to do what you're asking:

```
function demoDisplay()
{
  $("#clapper").show().delay(200).hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger event with using `click()` function.

**html:**

```
<a href="#" class="triggerElem"> TEST</a>
```

**javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function({

       $('.triggerElem').click(function() {
          $("#clapper, #clapperBG").show();//shows both element
          $("#clapper").fadeOut(200);
       });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy thing to do is to apply it to a click. Remove the onclick from the ahref and add a class or even dump the ahref alltogether and do a div/span doesnt matter.

```
 <div id="main">
 <a href="#" class="clickevent" > TEST</a>
 <div id="clapper"  > Some Animation GIF</div>
 <div id="clapperBG" class="animated  flipInY" >Background</div>



 </div>
```

Your jquery would look like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.clickevent').click(function(){
   $('#clapperBG').css({'display' : 'block'});
   });
  });
```

---

If you want to animate
use .show();
and use the slow
or use .toggle();

Comment: Thanks a lot! all of you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way to trigger a certain action after element clicking is to attach a click handle to that element. Consider the existence of `demoDisplay` function and the following HTML code:

```
<div id="main">
    <a id="test-link" href="#">TEST</a>
    <div id="clapper">Some Animation GIF</div>
    <div id="clapperBG" class="animated  flipInY" >Background</div>
 </div>
```

Inclusion of the event handler can be done using the jQuery in this way:

```
$("#test-link").click(demoDisplay);
```

If you want to show your elements first before fading out one of them it's better to use off-the-shelf jQuery function `show`:

```
function demoDisplay() {
    $("#clapper, #clapperBG").show();
    $("#clapper").fadeOut(200);
}
```